# Can you have an empty UILabel in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can a UILabel exist in the storyboard with height/width constraints but no text?

My app displays data from an API that occasionally lags for a brief second before loading, even with a 3 second delay I set for the LaunchScreen. I currently have those labels set to "0", but it would be better if they could just be blank.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: set to "" (blank string) in storyboard and update value of label once you get the data.

Comment: "Can a UILabel exist in the storyboard with height/width constraints but no text?"  I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Daljeet this might seem really dumb, but how can you add a blank string? programmatically, "" works... but in the storyboard wouldn't "" be understood as literally ""?

Comment: just set nothing(no text) for that label in storyboard thats it. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Daljeet Thank you! This solved the problem. Since they disappear from the storyboard, I thought the labels were being deleted. But, I was wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You will. You only have to set your label text empty

```
yourLabel.text = ""
```

:)

Comment: @JackJoseph Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad, set label text to empty string

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        yourlabel.text = ""
    }
```

From the storyboard:

[image]

And set your label value when you have data.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

just delete all text in storyboard
or clear it in `viewDidLoad`

```
myLabel.text = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set empty text for labels in the storyboard. There is no issue in that.

Go to storyboard and select label and set nothing(no text) for label.